# Detect a mouse click using a boolean value?

Tags: java

So I have the following method that is called every 20 ms:

```
public void update(Point mousePosition, boolean mouseDown) {
    //Creating an if statement that sees if the mouse is above the button   
    if(mousePosition.x > 50 && mousePosition.y > 50 && mousePosition.x < 125 && mousePosition.y < 100) {

    }
}
```

It will be passed in a coordinate of where the pointer is and I have created an if statement to detect when the pointer is above the button. Now using the boolean value `mouseDown`, I need to figure out how to detect a click and a double click.

For a single click I need to detect when `mouseDown` is true and then false (which I have no idea how to do) and for a double click, I think I will use `System.currentTimeMillis();` to see if that happens twice.

Please don't recommend something else besides using `mouseDown` I have to build this on top of other code and I need to stick with this method.

Comment: Why are you not using a [Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) which can detect when a mouse is over a component or when the mouse has been pressed/released?

Comment: Because I need to build this on top of code that someone else wrote and I'm not allowed to modify it.

Comment: you can use java swing to listen to your mouse.

Comment: I don't understand the design. Are you saying your have 2 separate JVM's that are running and you somehow pass the location of the JFrame and all its components to the second JVM?

Comment: I don't think so, the way it was explained to me I basically understood it as the the method is called and there is another class that feeds in the coordinates and wither the mouse is down or not.

Comment: So if you get `mouseDown` in this method unless you provide more code for us to actually see what's retrieving the mouse state/parameters there is no way to anser the question. There should be some interface that is pulling mouse position, button down/up, etc. but this is not this method.

Comment: According to the guy I talked to all I need to do is detect when Boolean variable has changed from true back into false. That's all that I really need to figure out right now.

Comment: `all I need to do is detect when Boolean variable has changed from true back into false.` - actually you need to know how many "falses" you have in a specified time period, as demonstrated in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare two if statements and have one of them set a global variable equal to true when the mouse is true and then set another if statement that will detect if the that global variable is true and if the mouse is not down.

Here is sudo code:

```
if(mouse is down)
{
   click=true;
}
if(click == true && mouse is not down)
{
   we have a click!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So a mouse click is generated when a mousePressed and mouseReleased event is generated at the same location.

So in the context of your method you would need to get a mouseDown == true and mouseDown == false at the same location.

A double click is determined by the time between 2 mouseDown == false events at the same location.

So you need to determine the time interval between the 2 events above to determine when a double click has occurred.

One way to do this is to start a Timer when the first mouseDown == false is received. If the Timer fires then you know no other events have be received and therefore you just experience a single mouse click.

However, is a second mouseDown == false is received before the timer fires then two event where generated in the time frame which means you have a double click event.

Here is example code that demonstrates the concept:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class ClickListener extends MouseAdapter implements ActionListener
{
    private final static int clickInterval = (Integer)Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().
        getDesktopProperty("awt.multiClickInterval");

    MouseEvent lastEvent;
    Timer timer;

    public ClickListener()
    {
        this(clickInterval);
    }

    public ClickListener(int delay)
    {
        timer = new Timer( delay, this);
    }

    public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getClickCount() > 2) return;

        lastEvent = e;

        if (timer.isRunning())
        {
            timer.stop();
            doubleClick( lastEvent );
        }
        else
        {
            timer.restart();
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        timer.stop();
        singleClick( lastEvent );
    }

    public void singleClick(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void doubleClick(MouseEvent e) {}

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame( "Double Click Test" );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.addMouseListener( new ClickListener()
        {
            public void singleClick(MouseEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("single");
            }

            public void doubleClick(MouseEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("double");
            }
        });
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
     }
}
```

The point of this code was to NOT generate the first single click event when a double click event is generated.

In your case you would want to generate the single click and then a double click if the event is within the time period. So obviously the code would need to be changed. I just wanted to demonstrate the concept of using the Timer to determine if two click occurred within the double click time frame.

So in your case the code would be a little simpler. You add the code to your `update(...)` method. Every time you receive a mouseDown == false you check the Timer.

if the Timer is running, you have a double click (and stop the Timer)

if the Timer is not running you have a single click (and you restart the Timer).

if the Timer fires an event you stop the Timer.